# Xen xl toolstack on Debian 7.3.0; can't ssh to VM

Tags: networking, ssh, debian, xen

I've got DOM0 and DOMU running (both Debian 7.3.0 AMD64), and can use both individually and can `ssh localhost` on both with the expected results.  I am setting up the networking by hand to understand how it all goes.  The problem comes down to, no matter what I try, if I `ssh w.x.y.z` on DOM0 in the hope of having a shell on DOMU, I always end up with a shell on DOM0; the vif-bridge does not seem to carry the traffic across and in to the DOMU.

Could someone describe the simplest setup which would achieve this, using just the `xl`, `ip`, `brctl` and `iptables` comands please?

To be more concrete and provide maybe a starting point, here's a setup I'm currently trying:

```
===/etc/xen/s1-0-2=============================

name="s1-0-2"
memory=2048
kernel='/root/s1-0-2--vmlinuz'
ramdisk='/root/s1-0-2--initrd'
extra='root=/dev/xvda1 -- console=hvc0'
e820_host=1
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/roots/s1-0-2,xvda,w' ]
vif=[ 'mac=02:12:12:12:12:02,bridge=s1-0-2' ]
vfb = [ 'type=vnc,vncdisplay=2' ]
vnc=1
stdvga=1

===============================================
```

And then on DOM0 (eth1 is a physical interface without a wire plugged into it):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
brctl addbr s1-0-2
brctl addif s1-0-2 eth1
xl create /etc/xen/s1-0-2
ip add add 10.133.33.3/24 dev eth1
```

working on the DOMU console:

```
ip add add 10.133.33.3/24 dev eth0
ip route add default via 10.133.33.3 dev eth0
```

and then when back on DOM0 I do

```
ssh 10.133.33.3
```

I get a shell prompt on DOM0, whereas I would hope for a shell prompt on DOMU.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I can see here that you have added the very same ip address to DOM0 and DOMU:

```
ip add add 10.133.33.3/24 dev eth1
```

and

```
ip add add 10.133.33.3/24 dev eth0
```

Most likely you have already figured this out.